Relative $dd^c$-lemma
Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a surjective map of compact Kähler varieties. Pick an open subset $U\subset Y$ and let $X_U$ be the preimage of $U$. Does the $dd^c$-lemma hold on $X_U$? Namely, let $\alpha$ be a $d$-exact $(p,q)$-form on $X_U$. Is it true that $\alpha = dd^c\beta$, possibly after shrinking $U$?
One approach, which doesn't work, would be to pick a function $f$ which is $1$ on $X_V$ for some $V\subset U$ and zero outside $X_U$. Write $\alpha = d\eta$. One is tempted to try to apply the $dd^c$-lemma to $d(f\eta)$, but unfortunately $d(f\eta)$ is no longer of type $(p,q)$.

This is false in general. Take $X=E\times U$ be the product of an elliptic curve and a ball in $\mathbb{C}$ with $f$ the projection, and let $\alpha=d(g\theta)$ where $g$ is a non-constant holomorphic function on $U$ and $\theta$ is a nontrivial $d$-closed $(0,1)$-form on $E$. Then $\alpha=dg\wedge\theta$ which cannot be $dd^c$-exact (even shrinking $U$), since its pullback to the fibers of $f$ vanishes. If we had $\alpha=dd^c u$ then $u$ would be constant on all fibers, hence be the pullback of a function on $U$, so $dd^cu$ is also pulled back from $U$, absurd
